# Calling ActionScript code from HTML JavaScript and obtaining return value?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

I need to obtain the text from the system clipboard in HTML JavaScript, in a way that it works on all browsers. Some form of clipboard.swf is sometimes used on many sites to copy text *into* the system clipboard.

How can I do the reverse, i.e. obtain the system clipboard's text in JavaScript via ActionScript code in a 1x1 swf file that I can embed in the page - the swf file can have code to get the clipboard text - How do I get this text in my JS code in the HTML page?

Thanks.

Comment: your question is not about AS-JS communication, but about clipboard. please rephrase the question in title

Answer (score 1):

Getting the clipboard contents is unavailable due to security reasons (for example, user just copied his password or something).

> **Note:** Because of security concerns, it is not possible to read the contents of the system Clipboard. In other words, there is no corresponding `System.getClipboard()` method.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002187.html